# C++ OpenCV How can I get the values of Binary Histogram image 0 and 255?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, binary, histogram

My code shows me values that are not accurate and i am not sure what else to try. My goal is to get the values of y such as rows, so that I can read the image and put it in an array.  Ive looked at examples and Stack Overflow is literally my last option.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
    #include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;

    int main()
    {
        Mat Rgb;
        Mat Grey;
        Mat image;
        //Mat Histogram;

        Rgb = imread("license.jpg", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvtColor(Rgb, Grey, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        threshold(Grey, image, 150, 250, THRESH_BINARY);

        int histogram[255];

        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            histogram[i] = 0;
        }


        for (int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++)
            //for (int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++)
            histogram[(int)image.at<uchar>(y)]++;
                //histogram[(int)image.at<uchar>(y, x)]++;

        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
            cout << histogram[i] << " ";

        // draw the histograms
        int hist_w = 512; int hist_h = 400;
        int bin_w = cvRound((double)hist_w / 255);

        Mat histImage(hist_h, hist_w, CV_8UC1, Scalar(255, 255, 255));


        int max = histogram[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < 256; i++) {
            if (max < histogram[i]) {
                max = histogram[i];
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            histogram[i] = ((double)histogram[i] / max)*histImage.rows;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
        {
            line(histImage, Point(bin_w*(i), hist_h),
                Point(bin_w*(i), hist_h - histogram[i]),
                Scalar(0, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
        }


        imshow("Image", image);

        waitKey(0);
        cv::destroyAllWindows();
        return 0;
    }
```

Results have numbers like 319 and other values and I am only looking to get 0 or 255

Comment: Can you please attach sample input image as well ?

Comment: Rgb = imread("license.jpg", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); what do you expect the AUTOSIZE to do?